# Decode image from base64 string

Tags: php, android, image, web-services, base64

I am sending an image to php server in the from of base64 string. When retrieving it from server side it shows size of the image,but it dont display the image I have posted to the service. Am using post method to send the string.

My android code://to encode the image.

```
Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Php code://to decode the image

```
$string=$_POST ['i_image'];
$filename="newimage.jpg";
$imagepath=base64_to_jpeg($string,$filename);

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
    fclose($ifp); 

    return $output_file; 
}
```

Can anyone help me to retrieve the original image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why exploding your data? if the data is clean base64 only decode it and write it directly into your file.

Comment: will it cause a problem in showing the image?

Comment: no it won't, there is no need to explode if you sending only clean base64 to your php endpoint

Comment: ok. eventhough i remove it from there it dont display the image. What am missing?

Comment: Does fwrite return the correct amount of bytes? PHP isn't the most familiar to me but.. have you tried fflush?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to decode your image in PHP i think this will help you

```
$uploadDir = 'path/to/download/dir/';
$binary = base64_decode($data_encoded_base64);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$fileName=md5(uniqid()).'.png';
$file = fopen($uploadDir . $fileName, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
```

hope it helps,
good luck!.